# Execute Command to read log file from Unix Server

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to read a log file to extract a exception generated at particular time.
I have executed below mentioned command to extract the exception but it will fetch the half exception string as  **ThreadPool.java:1593)** text contains 2 times in that string.

```
awk -v from='09/02/21 06:41:15:738' -v to='ThreadPool.java:1593)' '$0 ~ from ,$0 ~ to  {print $0}' mylog.log
```

Sample Log file .

```
  [09/02/21 06:41:15:738 IST] ERROR root - Error creating request
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)      Caused by :             org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
```

Out put received from command

```
[09/02/21 06:41:15:738 IST] ERROR root - Error creating request
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
```

The given command skips below logs

```
Caused by :             org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
```

Need help to extract complete track trace from log file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code, keep it up. Could you please do share more logs(samples only), which will help us to know which lines exactly we need to leave and which lines we need to print? That will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Is the sample log file extract posted all on one line or separate lines?

Comment: when i view the log file then it will show in different lines

Answer (score 0):

I'll try something a bit more generic:

```
awk \
    -v from='09/02/21 06:41:15:738' \
    -v to='^( |(Caused by))' '$0 ~ from , $0 !~ from && $0 !~ to {print $0}' \
    mylog.log \
    | sed '$d'
```

Sample `mylog.log`:

```
AAA TEST AAA
BBB TEST BBB
[09/02/21 06:41:15:738 IST] ERROR root - Error creating request
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
Caused by :             org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
CCC TEST CCC
DDD TEST DDD
```

GNU awk output:

```
$ awk \
    -v from='09/02/21 06:41:15:738' \
    -v to='^( |(Caused by))' '$0 ~ from , $0 !~ from && $0 !~ to {print $0}' \
    mylog.log \
    | sed '$d'
[09/02/21 06:41:15:738 IST] ERROR root - Error creating request
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
Caused by :             org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
            at com.abc.tx.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)
```

Explanation:

Instead of looking for a particular ending to an exception, we assume that all continuation lines of the stack trace start with spaces (we can generalize and use `[:space:]` if needed), so we set our `to` value to a regex that finds lines that begin with space of the phrase `Caused by`.

We then tell awk that the end pattern is `$0 !~ from && $0 !~ to`, meaning anything that doesn't look like our `from`, or like it's starting with a space, or like it's starting with `Caused by`.

That will also cause awk to print the line which matches the end pattern, i.e. the first line we **don't** want, so we delete the last line with `sed '$d'`.

Comment: I have tried this command but i got below output
`[09/02/21 06:41:15:738 IST] ERROR root - Error creating request            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)`

Comment: any suggestions